# Can't have 2 UI instances using google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet in which I've build a script (Web App) that displays a control panel with buttons using uiapp.

```
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight(160).setWidth(95);
```

However, when I open a Browser message box, or a htmlservice, it closes the control-panel.

```
Browser.msgBox('Backup Completed');
var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('BuildNotes').evaluate().setHeight(800).setWidth(1000).setTitle("Preview");
```

Can i only have one GUI up? Is there possibly a way to capture when a GUI is closed, so i can restart the control panel?

Answer (score 0):

Look up the help on browser.msgbox. it says there you can only use it as the last thing a script does as it terminates the script.